# Numerical Stable way of implement norm2 loss function

Tags: machine-learning, numeric

I have a loss function `mean{|| x^i - y^i ||^2}` where `x^i` is i-th data point. `|| x^i - y^i ||^2 = sum_j (x^i_j - y^i_j)^2`. (where `x^i_j` is the i-th data point's j-th variable)

I could easily have one of (x^i_j - y^i_j)^2 explodes up to `inf`

My alternative is to `logsumexp(2 * log(abs(x^i_j - y^i_j)))` to deal with norm2 but I could also have `x^i_j - y^i_j` to be zero. Is there numerical stable way of doing this ?

I tried `logsumexp(2 * log(abs(x^i_j - y^i_j) + 1e-20))` but no very good as I need differentiate this loss function backwards so the gradient still gives `Nan` sometimes